How to configure different logging levels for different loggers in Log4j2
We are trying to utilize Log4j2 in our project. We want to configure Log4j2 via properties files.
To reduce the noise in our logs, we want to set the root logger to info and set debug logging only for specific loggers or packages. How do we configure logging levels for each of our classes under development and not get debug messages for all the other loggers?
Here is an example we are using in our project:
status = warn
name = StackOverflow

# Console appender configuration
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d [%p] %c{1} - %m%n

# Root logger level
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger

# Only this class should be logging debug events
logger.mylogger.name = com.example.ClassUnderDevelopment
logger.mylogger.level = DEBUG

What would be the properties needed to configure Log4j2 to enable different log levels for different classes (named loggers)?

Log4j2 allows you to specify names and level dynamically:
logger.mylogger.name = com.example.ClassUnderDevelopment
logger.mylogger.level = DEBUG

logger.myotherlogger.name = com.example.AnotherClassUnderDevelopment
logger.myotherlogger.level = TRACE

As long as the second segment in the property key is unique, different configurations can be specified.

